# Using `this` for Parent Function inside a Nested Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, object

In the Apple "classs", how can the nested function `countSeeds()` retrieve the value `this.price`?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/VGqEa/

```
Apple = function() {
    this.price = 17

    this.cutOpen = function() {

        console.log(this.price);
        countSeeds();

        function countSeeds() {
            console.log(this.price);
        }
    }        
}


var apple = new Apple();
apple.cutOpen();
```

**Output**

```
17
undefined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

put `var self = this` at the top of Apple, and then refer to this as self instead in the nested function.

i.e.:

```
Apple = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.price = 17

    this.cutOpen = function() {

        console.log(this.price);
        countSeeds();

        function countSeeds() {
            console.log(self.price);
        }
    }        
}


var apple = new Apple();
apple.cutOpen();
```

You could also put the `self=this` statement at the beginning of this.cutOpen, since this will still refer to the Apple object in cutOpen (since it is a method of Apple).

**Update**

Most evergreen browsers now support arrow functions, so you can write it like:

```
Apple = function() {
    this.price = 17

    this.cutOpen = function() {

        console.log(this.price);
        let countSeeds = () => {
            console.log(this.price);
        };
        countSeeds();
    }        
}
```

This doesn't work in IE11 or other older browsers, unless you use some kind of transpiler to target older javascript.

Comment: Did `countSeeds()` change the `this` variable within itself?

Comment: The this object in the context of a function is set in one of three wasy: 1. If the function was called with new (new Apple) this refers to the object that will be returned by the constructor. 2. If the function is called on an object with dot syntax (apple.cutOpen()) or with the call or apply methods, then this refers to that object. 3. If the function is called directly ( countSeeds() ), then this refers to the global object, which in a browser is window.

Comment: You're forgetting `.call()`, `.apply()`, `.bind()`, the brackets syntax which is equivalent to the dot notation and the (soon to be standardized) arrow functions. The important thing to remember is that the `this` binding for the execution context is defined by the way the function is called.

Comment: One change I would make is that once you start to use `self`, use it for everything to avoid any confusion in your code. So the second line in your function would be `self.price = 17;`, and of course `self.cutOpen = function() {`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I didn't forget about .call() or .apply(), I mentioned them right after the dot syntax. I did miss bind though, and I didn't mention the arrow syntax because it isn't widely implemented yet (although when it is that would be the best answer to this question). Good call though.

Comment: oops, seems like my speed reading still has a couple bugs. Back on topic, @Nyxynyx here's one of my favorite articles about [understanding the this keyword](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) in case you're still puzzled. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you call a function without providing a context, `this` refers to `window` object. Try [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to set the context if you don't like the default:

```
this.cutOpen = function() {

        console.log(this.price);
        countSeeds.call(this); //use call to set the context for the function.

        function countSeeds() {
            console.log(this.price);
        }
    }
```

I suggest that you move the `countSeeds` to outside the constructor function to prevent it from being redefined multiple times:

```
function countSeeds() {
            console.log(this.price);
        }

Apple = function() {
    this.price = 17

    this.cutOpen = function() {

        console.log(this.price);
        countSeeds.call(this);
    }        
}
```

Or define `countSeeds` as a prototype's function:

```
 Apple = function() {
        this.price = 17

        this.cutOpen = function() {

            console.log(this.price);
            this.countSeeds(); //use countSeeds as an instance method.
        }        
    }

    Apple.prototype.countSeeds = function () {
          console.log(this.price);
    }
```

In my opinion, `countSeeds` in this case should be an instance method as ***it always accesses*** the `price` property of the current instance and ***could not work*** if `this` is `window`